# "Share your experience" type questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Have questions which ask people to share their experience with regard to a certain topic (i.e. share your experience introducing practice X to your team) generally been acceptable on stackoverflow?

These are questions that are not asking for a specific answer, but rather ask people to relate a story regarding an experience they had with regard to the topic.

The benefit of such questions is not to find an answer or to draw a conclusion, but rather to have a collection of stories that can help shed light on the issue with regard to trade-offs, consequences etc...

Or have these questions generally been considered too broad and too outside of the strict question and answer format?

Answer (score 4):

Sharing an experience is not solving a programing related problem. The question needs to deal **directly** with programming. This type of question does not belong. It's quite clear that what you want to ask isn't a problem, and on SO the words question and problem should be synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

> Or have these questions generally been
>   considered too broad and too outside
>   of the strict question and answer
>   format?

Such questions generally may be outside that format, but nevertheless *lots* of such questions exist on SO (and the other sites), and many have become very popular.

Usually such subjective questions are marked *[community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)* (often only after people complain about them not being CW...) which makes keeping them more easily acceptable to many people. (In CW mode posts can be more freely edited by the community, and they no longer generate reputation for their original poster.)

Comment: Why the -1? As Mr Skeet says, downvotes would be more useful with a comment. Oh well, all of what I wrote *is* true. :P

Comment: Your downvoter may be concern that you are encouraging the idea that "CW makes off-topic OK"...I am.

Comment: Actually, I encouraged no such thing. "Off-topic question" and "question with no definitive answer" certainly are *not* the same thing. Yes, there are many popular offtopic CW questions too, but most CW questions with no definitive answer are still very much programming-related. The concern you voiced is perhaps understandable, but wholly a misinterpretation.