# What is the best way to ask "Experience Specific" questions over SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

I regularly see guys pops up confused and frustrated with something that is purely based on someone's experience. for example, people usually ask *"What is the best way to..."* kind of questions.
This is something that is considered as *"Not Constructive"* by our community, but that kind of questions are sometimes pretty useful for newbies or someone who just want to kickstart without going through the phase of experiments and rejections before He/She can find the best thing to suit the purpose. Ok, not necessarily the best but at least it saves a great deal of time and resources.

Consider a questions like *"Best Practice To..."*, I admit this question will rapidly turn from QA to discussion and then into a brainstorming session, and yes, It sounds like the OP was a retard and didn't even cared to google it. There are so many experienced bloggers with cutting edge skills and you can easily find a gazillion articles on this topic but believe me I'd prefer to look over SE over google. Every answer here is to the point, no random scenario, no long and boring story that you must read before you can actually find the part you need out of it. and the best part of it, there are opinions and outcomes which can easily be filtered out.

I'd quote this user from ["Share your experience" type questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13253/224784)

> The benefit of such questions is not to find an answer or to draw a conclusion, but rather to have a collection of stories that can help shed light on the issue with regard to trade-offs, consequences etc...
>
> Or have these questions generally been considered too broad and too outside of the strict question and answer format?

So, I was wondering what would be the best way for newcomers to ask such a question ? Should they even ask this at first place ?

Comment: The answer is *probably* going to be they shouldn't be asking it at all. [Quora](http://quora.com) is trying an approach that is more suitable for what you describe, although the quality of the content will vary a lot - from truly fascinating accounts to meaningless grandstanding. But I guess that's the trade-off you make when you ask for experience

Comment: @Pekka웃: Their quality control... varies.

Comment: shouldn't experience based questions be asked at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @reikyoushin: Code review is for reviewing code ;), not experience questions.

Comment: oh ok, and there is still no 'what is the best way' subsite of stackexchange aotm?

Answer (score 6):

You answered your own question:

> I admit this question will rapidly turn from QA to discussion and then into a brainstorming session, and yes, It sounds like the OP was a retard and didn't even cared to google it.

The [SO mission statement begins with](https://stackoverflow.com/about):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site

Since we know that these types of questions easily turn into discussions, they should be discouraged.

You also said:

> here are so many experienced bloggers with cutting edge skills and you can easily find a gazillion articles on this topic but believe me I'd prefer to look over SE over google.

My personal opinion is that SO is useful because, in the absence of endless discussion, answers are easy to find. Ultimately, neither my nor your opinion is the deciding factor: the stated purpose of the site dictates the types of questions we should accept.

Answer (score 3):

This type of question is fine as long as it follows roughly the following form:

> This is the problem.  My approach was as follows:

```
> Probably some code
```

> I am uncertain of this approach because `___________`, `___________` or maybe `___________` (legitimate concerns).  Could someone shed some light on the holes in my approach or highlight some things I may not have considered?

At worst, people will say "what you're doing is fine" and the question will just tumbleweed.  If it *is* a good question then you will get responses pointing to holes in your approach.

It's important to explain that you already *have a solution*, but you are looking for *comments on that solution's quality*.

It's relatively new, but such questions may actually be good for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense